# Create statistics about https usage in apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, debian

I've setup https on my server. Nothing big, just to provide encryption. I was wondering how many users really use it. Is there a way to watch how many requests are over https and how many are not? The apache access log itself doesn't provide information about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set up separate access log for your https virtualhost with `customlog` directive. And use it for https usage analysis.